# Clear old ActionBar items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm facing a problem where i have an app with no actionbar.
I used a custom toolbar and I use this code for setup the toolbar

```
    private void setupToolbar(){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Shopping Cart");
    }
}
```

but the result shows an action bar with old items from mainActivity plus the toolbar added items.

Edited:
This is what looks like:
[image]

so you see two titles shown here
I want to remove the icons(except back icon) and the home title that was created in main activity

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "items", in "old items from mainActivity plus the toolbar added items"?

Comment: I have edited the question to include a screenshot of what happens

Comment: Those icons and the HOME item on the right are your options menu. If you don't want those, remove the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in your `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you so much I've used `invalidateOptionsMenu();` and that's works fine

Comment: ANother quetion please how to make a parallex toolbar that hides when user scroll down

Comment: With the support library, it's done with a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in a `CoordinatorLayout`. There's a basic example in [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792976).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First you change style and select NoActionBar :
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
and set CustomActionbar android :like this
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_core"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/img_left_arrow"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_header_back"
          android:visibility="visible" />
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Catagory"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/Moreappps"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_more_apps" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
I hope its help you
```